# Stability and Bifurcation Diagram

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bifurcation

if $ \frac{dx}{dt}= x(a^2-x^2) $ find and classify the stability of the equilibrium points, and draw the bifurcation diagram.

I have found the stability of the function at $x =0,-a,a$ I believe $0$ is a unstable equilibrium while $-a,a$ are both stable equilibrium. I then drew the bifurication diagram, it looks like the absolute value graph but sideways, is this correct?

Thanks!

Comment: I agree that the equilibrium points are $0,\pm a$, but can you say more about how you determined their stability?

Comment: Sure, I graphed a hypothetical A value, and saw that the graph went from positive to negative at both $a$ and $-a$ and went from negative to positive at zero. This implies $0$ is an unstable equilibrium. and $a, -a$ are stable actually.

Comment: Ok, good (that is correct, but the opposite of what you wrote in your original, which I think you also just realized).

Comment: correct, I did just realize and edited. I was more wondering about the bifurcation diagram

Comment: Are you supposed to include unstable equilibrium points in your bifurcation diagram (maybe with a dotted line)? Otherwise, yes, the lines for the stable equilibrium points are at $x = \pm a$.